# template structure constructor with reference parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, lvalue, rvalue

I've a template structure like this

```
template<typename ... Args> struct A;
template<>
struct A<>{

};
template<typename First, typename ... Args>
struct A<First, Args...>:private A<Args...>{
    typedef A<Args...> child;
    typedef A<First, Args...> self;
    typedef First type;
    static const size_t size = 1 + sizeof...(Args);
    type value;
    template<typename ... _Args>
    A(First && first, _Args && ... args) :child(forward<_Args>(args)...),value(move(first)){}//move
    template<typename ... _Args>
    A(const First & first, _Args && ... args) :child(forward<_Args>(args)...), value(first){}//assign
};
```

If I call this structure like below;

```
int f= 6;  
 A<int, int, int> g(f, 5, f); //it is working   
 A<int&> i(f);//not working  compile error
```

Second one not working cause rvalue constructor can't assign first to value.
 What should I do for second one work?

Comment: `_Args` is a reserved identifier (begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bigger problem is that when `First` is a lvalue reference (say, `T &`), both `First &&` and `const First &` becomes `T &`, meaning that your two constructors have the same signature, which is obviously illegal. (`const First &` is "reference to const `First`", but since references themselves are immutable , when `First` is a reference type itself the const is meaningless.)

One possible fix would be making your constructor take universal references for the first parameter as well, i.e.:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Cargs>
A(F&& first, Cargs && ... args) :child(forward<Cargs>(args)...),value(forward<F>(first)){}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c7052a20f642808).